# loading LWO using three js

Tags: 3d, three.js

I have a 3D file in LWO format. I have seen that we can load 3D files(.obj format) using three js using its OBJLoader.js, OBJMTLoader.js.
I have seen the 'loaders' directory of the latest three js version but couldn't find anything to load .lwo 3D files.
Is there any way I can load 3D lwo files using three js?

Answer (score 1):

You could download blender which is free 3D modeling software and import your lwo file and export it to .json or .obj file.

Comment: The .JSON exporter for Three.JS in Blender is a bit iffy at this time (R73).

Comment: The .JSON exporter for Three.JS in Blender is a bit iffy at this time (R73). Previous version exported a .js and now its .json but the loader method can throw errors if you select the wrong export option. I found the best results is import into Blender. Export OBJ. Use Python script found in the Three.js https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/converters/obj

Answer (score 1):

The faster pipeline is export trippled .OBJ from Modeler (w/ .MTL), import it into [threejs.org](https://threejs.org/editor/) Editor and export the .json .